# Pyautogui how to find a certain rgb color on a screen

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I am pretty new to coding, and I've recently stumbled upon pyautogui
and I have been trying to make pyautogui

find a certain color on a screen, but I can't get it to work
this is code:

```
color = (26, 13, 171)

s = pyautogui.screenshot()


for x in range(s.width):

    for y in range(s.height):

        if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:

            pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't work?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: if i leave it on it just doesnt click it and doesnt find it

Comment: I was just wondering whether it's not finding the color, or it is, but clicking on its location doesn't do what you think it should.

Comment: it could be because the color is really small im trying to make it find a link but a link is kinda small does that has something to do with it?

Comment: Your code is checking *every* pixel on the screen, so I doubt it. Where did you get the color value?

Comment: could it maybe be that it only checks once because after around 5 secs its says process finished maybe i should put it in a while loop that it only quits when it finds it

Comment: No, that's not it. Checking every pixel is a *very* time-consuming process — there's a lot of them. I think you have the color value wrong.

Comment: yh i checked and it should be right

Comment: Either it's wrong or clicking anywhere on it doesn't work.